# Adjusting image size for smaller sized screens

Tags: html, css, image, resize

Is there any way to make an image resize to the users screen size? (HTML/CSS)

I've tried Media queries, but they haven't proven very useful except for text I believe.

```
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
#dick{
    color: black;
    z-index: 400;
    position:absolute;
    left: 58%;
    top: 210px;
    height: 50%;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:100%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply making the width span as much as it can works.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You are an unrecognized genius, it has some flaws but I'll be able to code them out myself. Any way I can make text size change to a users screen size too?

Comment: Thanks, remember to mark it as the correct answer so that others won't have to review the other answers. Regarding the `font-size`, I use `em` with a "content first" approach to accomplish that. We can't go into depth here, you'd need to start another thread by posting another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class like **resize-img** and add this class to your img tag :

```
   <img class="resize-img">
```

and then in you stylesheet :

```
  @media screen and (min-width:600px) {

     .resize-img{

        width: 100px;
        height:200px;
        // and whatever else :d

    }

 }


   @media screen and (min-width:1000px) {

     .resize-img{

        width: 300px;
        height:600px;
        // and whatever else :d

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For image elements id.ot provides an answer. For background images, you can use this:

```css
html, body, .column {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/300x300') no-repeat 0px 0px/100vw;
    font-size: 10vh;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the header</h1>
<p>and some paragraph text</p>
```

Try to resize the window when using "Full page" view mode and see how the image resizes. If you don't care about distortion, you can even use

```
background: url('http://placehold.it/300x300') no-repeat 0px 0px/100vw 100vh;
```

By the way, `vw` and `vh` units can also be used to resize text (regarding your comment on id.ot's answer).